# Save excel file in postgres database and retrieving data

Tags: excel, reactjs, postgresql, flask

I want to save my uploaded excel file in database in raw wise. I have three column in my excel file, and i create a table in database with three column . now i want to save the excel file in postgres database using flask. i use react.js in front end. to show uploaded excel file i use 
**'react-excel-renderer'**
and written the above code

```
{this.state.dataLoaded &&
        <div>
        <Card body outline color="secondary" className="restrict-card">
        <OutTable data={this.state.rows} columns={this.state.cols} className= 
        {card.ExcelTable2007} tableHeaderRowClass="heading" />
        </Card>
    </div>}
```

Any help regarding this would be appreciated or if there is any other alternative way to save excel file and rendering please inform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to react. From react you will just upload your file to the flask server. In flask (python) you will convert csv/excel to dictionary, parse it and then insert data to your postgres DB. This might help you for postgres [CRUD](https://pynative.com/python-postgresql-insert-update-delete-table-data-to-perform-crud-operations/) ... If you need to know how to convert excel data into python dict refer this [library](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html).

If you have some implementation in flask then please share that so we might help you with parsing and inserting data into the database.

Thanks

Comment: what will be the excel file data type for saving in database?

Comment: You want to save the excel file in the database? or you want to save the rows of excel files in the database? As database rows?

Comment: Both are different. If you want to just save the excel file you can save it in `blob` format. But if you want to save the rows of excel file (i.e data of excel file) as table rows then you need to follow the steps i mentioned in the answer.

Comment: if i want to save the rows of excel file as table rows , how to identify the excel rows and insert them into database column ? i have name, email & phone rows.